# SharePoint 2013 with OneDrive Business on Windows Phone

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I've setup a test environment of SharePoint 2013 and configured MySites for OneDrive.
I would like to test this on a Windows Phone but obviously there is no Business App and don't see a way to sign in to my local site. iOS works fine with the Business App and my local SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go to the office app and then create a new place.  Just put in the url to your personal site.

Comment: Ok thanks, i had to install my Root Certificate on my WP because otherwise it wouldn't connect. I had hoped that it is more OneDrive integrated and you could Upload Pictures or other things from WP. Is it correct that i can only open Documents and edit.

Comment: Yea, pretty much.  They released a consolidated app but it only consolidates consumer onedrive and O365 onedrive for business.  Hopefully they will allow on-prem onedrive for business to also be setup in the app.  https://blog.onedrive.com/taking-the-next-step-in-sync-for-onedrive/